# When is the System.Threading.Task useful?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have used most of the Threading library extensively.  I am fairly familiar with creating new Threads, creating BackgroundWorkers and using the built-in .NET ThreadPool (which are all very cool).

However, I have never found a reason to use the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class.  I have seen maybe one or two examples of people using them, but the examples weren't very clear and they didn't give a high-level overview of why one should use a task instead of a new thread.

Question 1: From a high-level, when is using a task useful versus one of the other methods for parallelism in .NET?

Question 2: Does anyone have a simple and/or medium difficulty example demonstrating how to use tasks?

Comment: Tasks tend to be simpler to use, especially when you treat them as promises for work yet to be done.

Comment: Tasks (and the TPL) allow further abstraction over [a]sync operations. There are already is/was the IAsyncResult interface (which is often used by BeginXYZ/EndXYZ and is used by Task), but that is sort of awkward to use. The Task class provides a common "inversion" technique; instead of creating a new IAsyncResult type, a Task can execute "normal" code.

Comment: I don't think your Question 2 is suitable for SO.

Comment: @William I'm not sure, but I think “show me an example of X” is not actually a question, so it doesn't belong to a Q&A like SO.

Comment: @svick - I know that this question wasn't very specific, but it was one of those situations where I knew that there might be something to learn, but I wasn't sure how to ask the question correctly.  I think that your answer below was perfect though!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two main advantages in using `Task`s:

1. `Task` can represent any result that will be available in the future (the general concept is not specific to .Net and it's called [future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)), not just a computation. This is especially important with `async`-`await`, which uses `Task`s for asynchronous operations. Since the operation that gets the result might fail, `Task`s can also represent failures.
2. `Task` has lots of methods to operate on them. You can synchronously wait until it finishes (`Wait()`), wait for its result (`Result`), set up some operation when the `Task` finishes (`ContinueWith()`) and also some methods that work on several `Task`s (`WaitAll()`, `WaitAny()`, `ContinueWhenAll()`). All of this is possible using other parallel processing methods, but you would have to do it manually.

And there are also some smaller advantages to using `Task`:

1. You can use a custom `TaskScheduler` to decide when and where will the `Task` run. This can be useful for example if you want to [run a `Task` on the UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx),  [limit the degree of parallelism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx) or [have a `Task`-level readers–writer lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. `Task`s support cooperative cancellation through [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx).
3. `Task`s that represent computations have some performance improvements. For example, they use work-stealing queue for more efficient processing and they also support inlining (executing `Task` that hasn't started yet on a thread that synchronously waits for it).

Comment: +1, excellent answer. However, I would consider "Smaller #1" to be a main advantage, and replace "custom" with "specific". There are two commonly used built-in TaskSchedulers, one for background tasks which can run on any ThreadPool thread, and one for code which must run in a specific SynchronizationContext, e.g. on a UI thread. Point 2: You need not write a custom scheduler for this feature to be useful. Point 1: It's a huge benefit that the same model can be used for foreground and background units of future work.

Comment: A sophisticated concept answered in simple and plain English, hats-off!